# Connecting to Database using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I was trying to connect to the Atlas Mongo database using this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// connect to MongoDB
const dbURI = 'mongodb+srv://laajili:test1234@nodetuto.n1hyy.mongodb.net/node-DB?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then((result) => console.log('connected to db'))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

but I get this error on the terminal:
`MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster.` One common reason is that you're trying to access
the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/

does anyone have an idea about this topic ??

Answer (score 1):

Use a service like below to get your public IP address,

https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Within Atlas console go to Security -> Network Access -> IP Access List(Tab)

Within this you will have an option to "+Add IP Address".

Add your public IP address there and try again.

Comment: Thanks I already changed my configuration and gave it the permission to connect from anywhere on my atlas Dashboard.